# send metatags through Google Cloud Signed URL with Django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using signed url to get or post/put video fileq on my google storage. My modules refers on [signed_url V4](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually) and it's working quite well.
I wanted to add some metadata tags to my requests in order to manage more efficiently the charges related to GCS. But since I added those headers, the requests failed returning  a cors policy error : *(I have shortened the signature in the block above to make it more readable)*

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test-dev-slotll.storage.googleapis.com/uploads/dave/FR/eaa678c9/2020/9/785f/f45d3d82-785f_full.mp4?X-
Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=dev-storage%40brilliant-tower-264412.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20200926%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20200926T093102Z&X-Goog-Expires=3600&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-goog-meta-account&x-goog-signature=6fbb27e[...]bd0891d21' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and the detailed message:

```
   <Error>
    <Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code>
    <Message>Your request has a malformed header.</Message>
    <ParameterName>x-goog-meta-account</ParameterName>
    <Details>Header was included in signedheaders, but not in the request.</Details>
   </Error>
```

The cors are conigured to allow almost everything on my bucket :

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["*"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["*"]}]
```

and here is the Python/Django function

```
def _get_signed_url(self, http_method="GET"):
        """' create a signed url with google storage
        create a 'GET' request by default,
        add method='w' or 'put' to create a 'PUT' request
        get_signed_url('w')->PUT / get_signed_url()->GET
        """
        if http_method.lower() in ["w", "put", "post"]:
            http_method = "PUT"
        else:
            http_method = "GET"

        signed_url = generate_signed_url(
            settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME,
            self.file.name,
            subresource=None,
            expiration=3600,
            http_method=http_method,
            query_parameters=None,
            headers={'x-goog-meta-language':'french','x-goog-meta-account':'david',},
        )

        return signed_url
```

As I wrote it above, method get_signed_url() is copied from [signed_url V4](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually)
if i replace `headers =  {'x-goog-meta-language':'french','x-goog-meta-account':'david',},`
by `hearders = {}` or `headers = None` (as it was previously, it works fine

last, when I click on the link given by the signed-url, I got an  error message:

The signed url as well as blob uploading or downloading are working fine without the headers for months but I do not see why the server is responding that the header meta tags are malformed...
I will appreciate any help
thanks !

Comment: If you fix the cause of the MalformedSecurityHeader error, you’re likely going to find your existing CORS configuration is already working as expected. When the response status is not 200 OK but instead some error, it’s normal and expected that the response won’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: Yes I do not suspect the cors. The signed url works when I’m not sending additional headers and everything is authorized with cors. What i do not understand is why are my metadata malformed and why *headers = {‘x-goog-meta-language’: ‘fr’}* incorrect...

Comment: I have zero domain knowledge about the Google Cloud stuff, but I do notice the error cited in the question says, *“Header was included in signedheaders, but not in the request.”* That seems to indicate the problem isn’t that the value of the header is somehow malformed — but instead that the request header is simply missing altogether. So you might want to update the question to show a snippet of the part of your frontend JavaScript code that’s making the request. Is that code ensuring the right header gets included in the request?

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779529/how-to-create-a-file-upload-signed-url-using-google-cloud-platform, which seems to be about the same problem you’re running into. A deleted answer there says, *“This error means that you included the HTTP header <some-header-name> when you created the signature. This means that the client must also include this header when uploading.

Either remove the header before signing or modify the client software to include the <some-header-name> header when making the HTTP request.”*

Comment: I understand that the problem comes from the HTTP request. but the URL has been builded by GCP through the "generate_signed_url()" method that is provided by the "signed url v4 script". I just send the given URL to the client through a django template that "print" the link with the signed url. When  the user click in the link given by that URL, the client sends a GET request. As there is no way to modify the request in the link itself, how to insert headers in the request ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Sideshowbarker suggests it in his comments, the problem came from the client.
The signed url was used to send files to storage through ajax but no custom header were added to the ajax.
By specifying the headers in the ajax, the PUT request of a signed url with custom metadata works well.

```
function ajaxSendToStorage(uuid, url) {
  // Sending ONE file to storage
  var file = getFileById(uuid);
  $.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    contentType: file.type,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: file,
    url: url,
    headers: {"x-goog-meta-account":"david","x-goog-meta-language": "fr"},
    success: function() {},
    complete: function() {},
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message when I was performing a GET request on the pre-signed urls from GCP. Adding the content-type: "application/octet-stream" solved it for me.

```
ajaxCall_getFile = $.ajax({    
xhr: function() {
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
return xhr;
},
type: 'GET',
url: <PRE-SIGNED URL>,
contentType: "application/octet-stream",
processData: false,
success: function(file_data){
  alert("file downloaded");
},
error: function(err) {
  alert('Download failed, please try again.');
}
});
```