# GCS bucket generating presigned url for uploads

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to generate the presigned url for uploading files to buckets in GCS. But am having the following error when trying to open the link in the browser. Following is my code

```
package test;
import com.google.auth.Credentials;
import com.google.auth.ServiceAccountSigner;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.HttpMethod;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class TestGcs {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String extracted = extracted();
        System.out.println(extracted);
        
        
    }

    private static String extracted() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Credentials credentials = getCreds();
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .setProjectId("<<project ID>>")
                .build()
                .getService();

        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of("<<bucketname>>", "<<object Nmae>>")).build();

// Generate Signed URL
Map<String, String> extensionHeaders = new HashMap<>();
extensionHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS,
Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
Storage.SignUrlOption.signWith((ServiceAccountSigner) getCreds()),
Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extensionHeaders),
Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
return URLDecoder.decode(url.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    }

    private static Credentials getCreds() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("<<Json service account key path>>"));
        return credentials;
    }

}
```

I get the following error when accesing through browser. The service account role has storage admin role.

```
<Error>
<Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code>
<Message>Your request has a malformed header.</Message>
<ParameterName>content-type</ParameterName>
<Details>Header was included in signedheaders, but not in the request.</Details>
</Error>
```

Comment: What did you enter in the browser? Note the error message **Header was included in signedheaders, but not in the request**. Did you include the same header **Content-Type: application/octet-stream**? Use **curl** to test and post the command and the result in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley: I entered the url generated from above code which the value of "extracted". I used the folowing command  curl -X PUT --upload-file helo.txt <<signed URL>> and got an error which is too large to display here

Comment: How did you specify the header **Content-Type: application/octet-stream**? Put these details in your question. There is plenty of room.

Comment: @JohnHanley In the above code in the extension headers map, i put the content-type.

Comment: You must also put the same headers in the request when using the signed URL. Reread the error message. For testing, remove the header when signing to see how everything works.

Comment: Hi, I found this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291055/15774177), can you please try to use content-type in the curl command the way he has used it, it will be like this ``` curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' " --upload-file my-file 'signedURL’```, and tell us what you get.

Comment: @ZeenathSN : works with curl. But am facing issue with cors.I am not upload from browser through js code. I am getting the following error

Acess to XmlHttpRequest from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Have you configured the CORS on the bucket as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67568665/15774177)?